# ssh: connect to host HOSTNAME port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have trouble connecting to a server with `ssh` from my Lubuntu 14.04 computer, although it can be done from other machines. I can't get to the address online either (others can).

Am currently using a 3G network from my phone, but this doesn't seem to be the problem as I can connect to the server using another computer with the same 3G connection.

This is my attempt to connect:

```
root@Elizabeth:/# ssh USER@HOSTNAME
ssh: connect to host HOSTNAME port 22: Connection timed out
```

UPDATE: Saw that `ping HOSTNAME` renders the wrong IP-address, so I guess this could be a clue to what's wrong. Any way to solve that? I can get around it though by doing `ssh USER@IPADDRESS`, as suggested to me in a comment.

Some further info below, if it's useful. I'm new to working with servers and networking, so do say if there is other information needed to say what is wrong.

```
root@Elizabeth:/# nm-tool | grep "DNS"
DNS: 172.20.10.1
DNS: 172.20.10.1

root@Elizabeth:/# nslookup HOSTNAME
Server:        127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    HOSTNAME
Address: IP-address # correct IP-address for HOSTNAME

root@Elizabeth:/# ip route
default via 172.20.10.1 dev eth1  proto static 
172.20.10.0/28 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.10.3  metric 1 
172.20.10.0/28 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.10.5  metric 9
```

Comment: what happens if you `ssh user@ipaddress`?

Comment: That solved it - thanks a lot! Wasn't more complicated than that. I tried that earlier, but with the wrong IP-address, since I thought it'd be the IP-address that was shown when doing `ping hostname`, but that actually gave the wrong IP address for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To properly test your ssh use `ssh user@ipaddress`. If that fails, the issue is something deeper like the connection.

Comment: What can I do if it fails `ssh user@ipaddress` ?

Comment: Check the connection from 1 machine to other by pinging. `ping 192.168.1.2` for example. Use the same ip you are trying to connect to. If you can't ping you cant connect.

Comment: What if ping works but not ssh?

Comment: if you ping the connection is working, if ssh still fails, its probably a configuration error. Could be a firewall if you are outside the network

Answer (score 9):

To properly test your ssh use `ssh user@ipaddress`. If that fails, the issue is something like the firewall.

For example, checkout firewall status with below code

```
sudo ufw status
```

If it is working then first deactivate firewall with below code:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

and test `ssh user@ipaddress`

Answer (score 9):

Allow ssh to ufw will solve the problem. Run the below command to allow.

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Comment: i need to ssh to run this.

Answer (score 1):

Allow ssh and port 22 from ufw, then enable it and check with status command

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status
```

Answer (score -1):

please go to the Network setting, choose the Ethernet connection and disable all Ethernet connection only connect to the Wi-fi. after that go to your terminal and write ssh username@ipaddress (ssh stackoverflow@161.10.10.1)

Comment: Using a different connection makes no sense and isn't in any way possible related with the question. The only useful part of this answer is a copy of the other answers.