# Can't reach certain web site/server via DNS, only with ip

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns

I am having trouble getting to a certain server/website online and also connecting to the server with `ssh USERNAME@HOSTNAME`. Am using a machine with Lubuntu 14.04. I can connect to the server from all other computers I have tried.

My main problem is that I can't get to any websites on the server in a web browser (using Firefox) - the `ssh`-ing isn't a problem, as I can do it using `ssh USERNAME@IP-ADDRESS`.

I have also seen that `ping HOSTNAME` renders the wrong IP-address, so I guess this could be a clue to what's wrong?

Some further info below, if it's useful. I'm new to working with servers and networking, so do say if there is other information needed to say what is wrong.

```
root@Elizabeth:/# nm-tool | grep "DNS"
DNS: 172.20.10.1
DNS: 172.20.10.1

root@Elizabeth:/# nslookup HOSTNAME
Server:        127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    HOSTNAME
Address: IP-address # correct IP-address for HOSTNAME

root@Elizabeth:/# ip route
default via 172.20.10.1 dev eth1  proto static 
172.20.10.0/28 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.10.3  metric 1 
172.20.10.0/28 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.10.5  metric 9
```

(This question is similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650518/ssh-connect-to-host-hostname-port-22-connection-timed-out) one, but that question didn't focus on the browsing problem.)

Comment: What is “the server” and did you set it up yourself? What is `172.20.10.1`? How namely looks an URL that doesn’t work, and where do you try to access it?

Comment: The server is set up by a university, ws1.bmc.uu.se, which I'm trying to access in Firefox. I'm afraid I don't know what `172.20.10.1` is. I just thought there could be something wrong with the DNS, so I though the output of `nm-tool` might perhaps help someone solve it.

Comment: For me, http://ws1.bmc.uu.se redirects to http://it.bmc.uu.se/webservice.php . Where is the problem?   
By the way, ws1.bmc.uu.se has address 130.238.55.19   is it you?

Comment: So, I can get to http://it.bmc.uu.se/webservice.php (but am not directed there from http://ws1.bmc.uu.se). And I really want to get to a website under this domain name, where you need a special link with hash and id to get in (which I have, but still can't get there). Can't seem to get to anywhere on this domain name.

Comment: Do you try to access ws1.bmc.uu.se **from the same LAN?** It’s a known problem with cheap buggy routers or incompetent setup.

Comment: No, I'm on a different network. And 130.238.55.19 is the correct IP address of ws1.bmc.uu.se. But when I ping it I get a different IP address (130.238.39.248).

Comment: Oops, just understood what are you speaking about. **Where exactly** do you resolve ws1.bmc.uu.se as 130.238.39.248? How recently was the it added to bmc.uu.se?

Comment: In Lubuntu 14.04 terminal using `ping ws1.bmc.uu.se`. Don't understand the last quesion, sorry, am not so used to this.

Comment: Then your current workstation queries a buggy nameserver. Look what does `/etc/resolv.conf` contain and contact admins of that servers. Note that if domain record for ws1.bmc.uu.se was changed **recently** (within 24 hours), then it might be a transient phenomenon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29074/discussion-between-ingrid-and-incnis-mrsi).

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS at the workstation [was sabotaged](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/29074/2015/9/12#24056014) with:

```
130.238.39.248  ws1.bmc.uu.se
```

in `/etc/hosts`.